# SQL запрос: в переменную ничего не заносится

Tags: mysql

Доброго времени суток! Подскажите, почему в переменную ничего не заносится?

```
 select  sum(amount) into @t from orders;
```

Comment: а че ето такое?))))

Comment: ну по идее в переменную t должно должна занестись сумма содержимого полей amount из таблицы orders

Comment: это ты хранимую процедуру пишешь?

Comment: да, её самую

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT [@t](/users/94/tom) = SUM(amount) FROM orders